# What is the best way to feed the image+vector dataset to Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to do a Deep Learning project by using Tensorflow.

Each of my data sets contains 2 files( PNGimage file + TXTvectors file ), where are put in different folders as follow:

```
./data/image/  #Folders contains different size of images 
./data/vector/ #Folders contains vectors of corresponding image
#For example: apple.png + apple.txt
```

The example content of vector shows as follow:

```
10.0,2.5,5,13
```

And since image size are different, the resize and some transformation apply on vectors are required. It is important to make sure that I can do these processing during Tensorflow is running. Is there any good way to manage this kind of datasets?

I referred to a lot of basic tutorial however most of them are not so many details about arrange customized data input and output. Please give me some advice!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at [TFRecords](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/python_io#tfrecords_format_details) and [queues](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data). Basically the idea is the following: you resize all your images to the same format and store them together with your txt vectors in one TFRecord file. This is done separately before you run your model.

When you create your model you create a queue which reads data from the TFRecord file and feeds it to your model.

Comment: Still not very understand the how to read and "input for training". Do you have any "full example"??